# PrestaShopException Current theme unselected

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i got this error after installing PrestaShop on another machine and i don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me .

[PHOTO ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C19DI.png)

I changed in database in thable "ps_configuration" the PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL values.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `ps_shop` table. It has a field called `theme_name`. Be sure that every row in that table has a value for that field that match a folder name inside themes dir.